# Problem with file uploader on Django after deploy

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker, google-cloud-platform

I have a site with file uploader developed on django. But after deployment when I upload a file from one device, the same file becomes visible to all other devices on which the site is opened. But I need each user can upload his file and work with it independently.

For example, on this site https://pixmiller.com/en/remove-background/ if I upload pictures from different devices, they will not interfere with each other. And I would like that my site works in this way.

How can this problem be solved? Thank for any ideas.

For your information: for deployment I have used Docker and Google Cloud.

I don't want to create authentication system at this stage.